# Monetizing Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

Anyone else notice that links to Amazon, like [HERE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/97965/11684), end up with a Stack Exchange tag on them?  Not objecting, but I do think that disclosure of the rules we're playing by would be a positive.

Comment: There is a post on meta.stackexchange about it, I failed to quickly dig it up, maybe someone else has more luck

Comment: That link is no longer valid

Comment: @laptop2d -- Thanks.  Looks like the original was deleted, so I changed the example to an old answer of mine that I should have included an amazon link for anyway

Answer (score 7):

Interesting - I suppose that's better than having to police amazon links as spam.

[Auto-inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

Comment: Wow- longstanding policy!  I guess I haven't clicked through on Amazon links, or just never noticed.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, I learned something today as well.

Comment: I can't comment on that Meta, I'd like to ask why ALL amazon links aren't converted to a Stack Exchange referral, not just for books.

Comment: @HilarieAK Sorry, I don't know that answer.